# Stepped line chart with realtime chart.js plugin

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is any possibility to create stepped line chart but with realtime plugin?

```
datasets.forEach((dataset => {
         dataset.data.push({
                  x: now,
                  y: this.getSignalValue(dataset.label.split(' ')[0]),
                  stepped: true
                  })
         }))
```

In normal chart with chart.js stepped property is doing the job, is any equivalent in realtime chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the steped propery in the data itself, this wont work. You need to configure it in the dataset like so:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

//lets simulate 'simutime'
let simutime = Math.floor(Math.random(100) * 100);
setInterval(() => {
  //i added some random values just to have raising values like in my original simutime from matlab model
  simutime += 3;
}, 500);

const data = {
  datasets: [{
      label: "Mains_1_Voltage",
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      stepped: true
    },
    {
      label: "Mains_1_Frequency",
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(248, 109, 181, 1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(163, 109, 181, 1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      stepped: true
    }
  ]
};
const config = {
  type: "line",
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          title(items) {
            if (items.length) {
              const item = items[0];
              const {
                chart,
                datasetIndex,
                dataIndex
              } = item;
              const simutimeData = chart.data.datasets[0].data[dataIndex];
              return 'Simutime: ' + simutimeData.simutime;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'realtime',
        realtime: {
          delay: 1000,
          onRefresh: chart => {
            // get unique time stamp for all data
            const now = Date.now();
            // check if the simutime is already stored
            // if yes, set undefined
            const data = chart.data.datasets[0].data.filter(element => element.simutime);
            let simu = simutime;
            if (data.length) {
              const lastData = data[data.length - 1];
              if (lastData.simutime === simu) {
                simu = undefined;
              }
            }
            chart.data.datasets[0].data.push({
              x: now,
              y: Math.random() * 100,
              simutime: simu
            });
            chart.data.datasets[1].data.push({
              x: now,
              y: Math.random() * 100
            });
          }
        },
        ticks: {
          // this forces to use the data for ticks 
          source: 'data',
          callback(value, index, ticks) {
            const tickValue = ticks[index].value;
            if (tickValue) {
              const dataset1Data = this.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
              const data = dataset1Data.filter(element => element.x === tickValue);
              if (data.length) {
                return data[0].simutime;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100
      },
    },
  },
};
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.0.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@1.2.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-streaming@2.0.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-streaming.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="myChartDiv">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```